# Disable printing of pages with hidden text

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Certain pages within my document are completely made up of hidden text. Each page commences with Heading 2 style and starts on a new page.

The Table of Contents updates and removes each hidden page, however, the page itself is still printing - as a blank page.

How can I stop the page from printing?

Comment: Is this in Microsoft Word, or another word processor? Also, what version of the software are you using (2007, 2010, 2013, etc)?

Comment: Microsoft Word 2010

Comment: Next time please edit your post to include such important information. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried determining why the page is still printed? Does it show up in print preview? Can you modify any of the text on the previous page so it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the page numbers of the pages without text, you can manually tell Word to not print those pages. Go to File > Print and under Settings, type the page numbers of the pages you do want printed: 1,2,5,6,7-12

I don't think there is a way to automatically not print those pages.